# How to run varnish cache without IPv6?

Tags: cache, varnish

Operating system: `debian 9`, varnish version: `5.0.0`

I have turned off IPv6 support on my machine and varnish crashes upon start with the following error:

```
Error: Cannot open socket: :6081: Address family not supported by protocol
```

I know this question has been asked here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40386558/varnish-cache-installed-but-not-starting-error-cannot-open-socket-6081-address), but it does not solve my problem. Also, I can't find any IP-related configuration option in the config files.

So, how can I run varnish cache without IPv6 support?

Comment: how exactly did you turn off IPv6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the main listen address/port is specified in the DAEMON_OPTS variable in `/etc/default/varnish` file as `-a :6081`, which means both IPv4 and IPv6, port 6081.

Try explicitly specifying an IPv4 listen address with the port: for example, if your system's IP address is 192.168.100.1, edit the address/port option to `-a 192.168.100.1:6081`.